# Solving an Equation For Multiple Values in Octave

Tags: octave

Trying to solve:

```
T = 6.11^(5400((1/273)-(1/T)))
```

where:

```
T =[273, 283, 293, 303]
```

Can't seem to get the syntax down. Any help would really be appreciated!

Comment: Please read the [documentation](https://octave.org/doc/v6.1.0/Arithmetic-Ops.html).

Answer (score 1):

T is a matrix, so if you try just defining T and entering it into the equation, you're going to be doing a lot of matrix math you probably don't intend. As @Sardar mentioned in his comment, to instead do vectorized operations on all of the values in parallel, you want to use the elementwise, or 'dot', versions of multiplication, division, and exponential operators. See https://octave.org/doc/latest/Arithmetic-Ops.html

Note also that you can't use parentheses as implied multiplication, you need a *

Then you should get the following:

```
>> T =[273, 283, 293, 303];

>> T = 6.11.^(5400.*((1/273)-(1./T)))
T =
   1.0000    3.5432   11.5160   34.6268
```

Also note that reusing T like this overwrites your input vales with the output values of T. Be sure that's what you want to do.